# Restricting Delete/Update on a table for a Login

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-delete, database-trigger

Is there a way to restrict a particular user from making any **modification** on particular table.

I am thinking to create a `Instead` of trigger and some how get the login info and restrict the user from running `delete/update` statements.

But is there any better way to do this, like Sql server has some login permission setting to restrict this

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1138/giving-and-removing-permissions-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd revoke all privileges first (assuming you already have the user)

```
REVOKE ALL
ON {object_name}
FROM {user_name}
```

Then grant only SELECT to that user.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT
ON {object_name}
TO {user_name}
```

Comment: I believe OP wants INSERT capability too.

Comment: Didn't think of this much simpler way. The way I searched in Google pulled some big big things like instead of trigger, DDL triggers etc.. Thank you